# How to use fairseq interactive with multiple gpu?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model, fairseq

I am trying to generate new prediction for the model, but I found it is not that intuitive to use fairseq. I found `fairseq-interactive` could help to generate with a good settings of batch_size, however, it seems that it will use 1 GPU at a time, I wonder if it is possible to use multiple GPU? Hope someone can kindly help!

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this natively within fairseq. The best way to do this is to shard your data and run `fairseq-interactive` on each shard in the background. Be sure to set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` for each shard so you put each shard's generation on a different GPU. This advice also applies to `fairseq-generate` (which will be significantly faster for large inference jobs).